# TTS in webview like webpage reader app

Tags: android, webview, text-to-speech

I am developing application like web page reader.I find this link
         https://github.com/kaze0/Talking-Browser and integrate TTS to my app.

what i implemented is,

```
     * If i click particular paragraph,it will highlight and read that paragraph.
       But i need to switch over next paragraph automatically.
```

What i need is,

```
       For example,
       webview consists 4 paragraphs and once i click first paragraph it 
       should highlight and read each paragraph continously.
```

Share ur thoughts...